# How can I update my FinishedOn and DeletedOn columns without hard coding a check against a different table's column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ODataTaskResult_Create]
    @ODataTaskId BIGINT,
    @ODataTaskResultTypeId INTEGER,
    @Details CHARACTER VARYING(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO [ODataTaskResult] WITH (ROWLOCK, XLOCK) ([ODataTaskId], [ODataTaskResultTypeId], [Details], [CreatedOn])
        VALUES (@ODataTaskId, @ODataTaskResultTypeId, @Details, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())

        DECLARE @ODataTaskResultTypeName CHARACTER VARYING(255)
        SET @ODataTaskResultTypeName = (
            SELECT TOP 1 [ODataTaskType].[Name] FROM [ODataTaskType]
            WHERE [ODataTaskType].[Id] = @ODataTaskResultTypeId)

        IF (@ODataTaskResultTypeName = 'Finish')
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [ODataTask]
            SET [ODataTask].[FinishedOn] = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
            WHERE [ODataTask].[Id] = @ODataTaskId
        END ELSE IF (@ODataTaskResultTypeName = 'Delete')
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [ODataTask]
            SET [ODataTask].[DeletedOn] = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
            WHERE [ODataTask].[Id] = @ODataTaskId
        END ELSE
            RAISERROR('Invalid result type', 16, 1)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
```

This procedure is supposed to look at the incoming `@ODataTaskResultTypeId` parameter, pull the result type down from another table, and do something based on the `Name` column in that record.

Basically when a result is entered against a task, it defines how it completed. If a task is finished, I need to modify the `FinishedOn` column on the parent task record and **not** alter the `DeletedOn` column. We have a constraint that indicates `FinishedOn` and `DeletedOn` may not both be `NOT NULL`.

Feeling at this point that since I have hard coded the different case logic into the stored procedure, it makes maintainability difficult and prevents this from working properly unless the `ODataTaskResult` table has the correct initial entries.

Should I make the `ODataTaskResult_Create` procedure only create the result and then have another procedure called `ODataTask_Finish` as well as another procedure called `ODataTask_Delete`?

Is there a different approach to this problem that is generally easier to maintain?

We never hard delete entries, only soft delete.

Comment: For only two types, it may not be worth making more complicated. But, if you want to be more flexible, add a column to your `DataTaskType` table that indicates the stored procedure to run after the `DataTaskResult_Create`. Then use a bit of dynamic SQL to dispatch.

Comment: @Laurence I like the idea of creating a sort of continuation for the stored procedure. You should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a flexible solution, you can add a column to your `ODataTaskType` table to hold the stored procedure to run afterwards. You can then use some dynamic sql to dispatch. If the column is called `PostComplete_Proc`, say:

```
create proc dbo.[ODataTaskResult_Create]
    @ODataTaskId bigint,
    @ODataTaskResultTypeId int,
    @Details varchar(max)
as

declare
    @proc sysname,
    @params nvarchar(max) = '@ODataTaskId bigint'

begin transaction
    insert into dbo.[ODataTaskResult] with (rowlock, xlock) (
        [ODataTaskId], [ODataTaskResultTypeId], [Details], [CreatedOn]
    ) values
        @ODataTaskId, 
        @ODataTaskResultTypeId, 
        @Details,
        sysdatetimeoffset()
    );

    select top 1 -- Would there really be more than 1? Why hide potential errors?
        @proc = PostComplete_Proc
    from
        dbo.[ODataTaskType]
    where
        Id = @ODataTaskResultTypeId;

    if @proc is null
        raiserror('Invalid result type', 16, 1);
    else
        exec @proc, @params, @ODataTaskId;

commit transaction;
```

then create the relevant stored procedures. If you have many result types and few procedures, you can even add another level, where the procedures are stored on a separate table and referenced via foreign keys.

I find it hard to convince myself that `rowlock, xlock` is doing anything here.

Comment: I added `ROWLOCK, XLOCK` because a page lock was being acquired (as indicated by our tester and their profiler, it really doesn't make sense to me either) and unnecessarily blocking concurrent inserts.

Comment: Ah, does `ODataTaskResult` not have a primary key?

Comment: The primary key of `ODataTaskResult` is the same as the primary key of `ODataTask`, it's a foreign primary key, so maybe that's causing an issue? SQL Server should be smart enough to know it's going to be unique because of the fact that the key in the other table is unique.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray A unique index would help with locking if the table doesn't already have one. However, if your tester is thrashing things, you could be getting lock escalation.